# HTML Required attribute not working on a simple Input

Tags: html

*NOTE: I am running Google Chrome version 45

The "required='required'" HTML attribute has worked flawlessly for me in the past, however now I am encountering an issue where this attribute just does not work at all. I just want to know what (simple) error I have made, because I cannot work it out for the life of me.

Here is the form:

```
        <div class="register_wrap">
            <h2 style="font-size: 26px; color: #999; font-weight: normal;">Register your team to play in an upcoming Oceanic eSports tournament</h2>
            <form action="enter_a_tournament.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label style="font-size: 18px;">Team Name</label><br /><input placeholder="Team Name" type="text" name="team_name" size="48" required="required"/><br /><br />
                <label>Player 1</label><br /><input placeholder="In Game Leader" type="text" name="player1" size="48" required="required"/><br /><br />
                <label>Player 2</label><br /><input placeholder="AWP'er" type="text" name="player2" size="48" required="required"/><br /><br />
                <label>Player 3</label><br /><input placeholder="Entry Fragger" type="text" name="player3" size="48" required="required"/><br /><br />
                <label>Player 4</label><br /><input placeholder="Support Fragger" type="text" name="player4" size="48" required="required"/><br /><br />
                <label>Player 5</label><br /><input placeholder="Lurk Fragger" type="text" name="player5" size="48" required="required"/><br /><br />
                <h2 style="font-size: 22px; color: #999; font-weight: normal;">Extra Team Information</h2>
                <label>Team Leader Steam ID</label><br /><input placeholder="Enter Team Leader Steam ID" type="text" name="team_leader" size="48" required="required"/><br /><br />
                <label>Steam Group URL</label><br /><input placeholder="Enter Steam Group URL" type="text" name="steam_group" size="48" required="required"/><br /><br />
                <label>Website URL</label><br /><input placeholder="Enter Website URL" type="text" name="steam_group" size="48" /><label style="font-size: 13px; color: red;"> *Optional</label><br /><br />
            </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `required` attribute does still work. But your form is missing a submit button. Browsers do not submit forms without a submit button and thus also do not validate any inputs.

Add a submit button (`input[type="submit"]` or `button[type="submit"]` or `button` [a button element without a type is a submit button too]):

```html
<div class="register_wrap">
  <h2 style="font-size: 26px; color: #999; font-weight: normal;">Register your team to play in an upcoming Oceanic eSports tournament</h2>
  <form action="enter_a_tournament.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label style="font-size: 18px;">Team Name</label><br /><input placeholder="Team Name" type="text" name="team_name" size="48" required="required"/><br /><br />
    <label>Player 1</label><br /><input placeholder="In Game Leader" type="text" name="player1" size="48" required="required"/><br /><br />
    <label>Player 2</label><br /><input placeholder="AWP'er" type="text" name="player2" size="48" required="required"/><br /><br />
    <label>Player 3</label><br /><input placeholder="Entry Fragger" type="text" name="player3" size="48" required="required"/><br /><br />
    <label>Player 4</label><br /><input placeholder="Support Fragger" type="text" name="player4" size="48" required="required"/><br /><br />
    <label>Player 5</label><br /><input placeholder="Lurk Fragger" type="text" name="player5" size="48" required="required"/><br /><br />
    <h2 style="font-size: 22px; color: #999; font-weight: normal;">Extra Team Information</h2>
    <label>Team Leader Steam ID</label><br /><input placeholder="Enter Team Leader Steam ID" type="text" name="team_leader" size="48" required="required"/><br /><br />
    <label>Steam Group URL</label><br /><input placeholder="Enter Steam Group URL" type="text" name="steam_group" size="48" required="required"/><br /><br />
    <label>Website URL</label><br /><input placeholder="Enter Website URL" type="text" name="steam_group" size="48" /><label style="font-size: 13px; color: red;"> *Optional</label><br /><br />
    
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried this with no success, it doesn't even seem to be working with the "Run code snippet" button on this website.

Comment: @ZeddZeppelin It does for me when using Chrome, Firefox or Opera. Are you using some really old browser? Or did disable the HTML5 form validation through some browser plugin? Can you test that from another browser or even another computer/device?

Comment: Running Chrome version 45, I'll test another computer though.

Comment: @ZeddZeppelin Well – it is possible that this is due to a Chrome bug. But I'am running Chromium 45 as well (Version 45.0.2454.85 Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit) and it does work.

Comment: Indeed, and I have not changed/added anything (I can remember) to Chrome since the last time I tried to use the required attribute and back then I had no problems.